# My proxy/program will not work/update? Python 3.4

Tags: python, proxy

```
import urllib.request
```

I am new to the community
Here is my .py

```
proxy= urllib.request.ProxyHandler({"http" : 'http://'removed for SF':'same'})

testip=urllib.request.urlopen('http://httpbin.org/ip').read()

testpip=urllib.request.urlopen('http://httpbin.org/ip', proxies=proxy).read()
```

Then I test in the Shell with `testip` and then `testpip`,
and the ip addresses match.

which they should !match

Comment: found the solution! 

import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen

proxy= {"http" : 'http://'proxyhere':8081'}


proxy_support=urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies=proxy)
opener=urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_support)
urllib.request.install_opener(opener)

getip= urlopen('http://httpbin.org/ip').read()

#and finally it returns a new ip